# Spring boot 2 fail to enable zipkin/sleuth with default configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring boot application with below configuration :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: 'active-listener'
  profiles: 'dev'
  sleuth:
    async:
      enabled: false
    annotation:
      enabled: true
  enabled: true
  sampler:
    probability: 1.0
  zipkin:
    baseUrl: http://localhost:9411
    enabled: true
```

Required zipkin tracing feature.

But my application not listing on zipkin server used proper jar also as below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

After continue efforts and going throgh core api of spring boot application I got my solution:)

Root cause of my issue is below :

> MY application using Spring boot RabitMQ integration and due that
> zipkin taking 1st prefrance to RabitMQ sender and my trace are ignored
> my zipkin server.

So use below configration is anyone has same issue to avoid lot painless efforts , even we are not getting in logs of server root cause of it

*---

```
spring:
  application:
    name: 'active-listener'
  profiles: 'dev'
  sleuth:
    async:
      enabled: false
    annotation:
      enabled: true
  enabled: true
  sampler:
    probability: 1.0
  zipkin:
    baseUrl: http://localhost:9411
    enabled: true
    sender:
      type: web*
```